# Monitoring the LMAX Disruptor

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern, lmax

How to monitor the LMAX Disruptor? Say I have 3 ringbuffers and wish to provide a ui that will give me information of the ringbuffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important property you probably want to monitor is the remaining capacity so that you can tell if the consumers are keeping up.

The simplest way to expose that would be to create a bean which can read the `RingBuffer.remainingCapacity()` and expose that via JMX. That way you can get remote monitor GUI's e.g. JConsole, JVisualvm, stats logging/monitoring via [graphite](https://github.com/graphite-project/), [openNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) or [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)

Comment: any example on how to expose it as a bean?